# Group by and divide in sections

Tags: php, laravel

I want to show my rows, but I want to divide them into sections and group them by their type ID.

```
Section 1
---------
<item>
<item>

Section 2
---------
<item>
```

I could easily do it in my blade view like below...

```
@foreach($types as $type)
<h1>{{ $type->name }}</h1>
<div class="list">
    <ul>
        @forelse(App\Equipment::where("type_id", $type->id)->get() as $item)
        <li>
            {{ $item->name }}
        </li>
        @empty
        <li>No results found.</li>
        @endforelse
    </ul>
</div>
@endforeach
```

However this is not effective and I need to implement a query in my controller instead, as I have query parameters I need.

```
public function index(Request $request) {
    $item = \DB::table("equipment");

    $appends = [];

    foreach(["type_id", "sockets", "quality_id", "one_hand"] as $field) {
        if($request->has($field)) {
            $appends[$field] = $request->input($field);
            $item->where($field, $request->input($field));
        }
    }

    if($request->has("class")) {
        $appends["class"] = $request->input("class");
        $item->where(["class_id" => $request->input("class")])
            ->orWhere(["class_id2" => $request->input("class")], ["class_id3" => $request->input("class")]);
    }

    if($request->has("name")) {
        $appends["name"] = $request->input("name");
        $item->where("name", "like", "%" . $request->input("name") . "%");
    }

    if($request->has("stats")) {
        $stats = $request->input("stats");
        $appends["stats"] = $stats;
        foreach($stats as $stat) {
            $item->where("stat_1", $stat)
                ->orWhere("stat_2", $stat)
                ->orWhere("stat_3", $stat)
                ->orWhere("stat_4", $stat)
                ->orWhere("stat_5", $stat)
                ->orWhere("stat_6", $stat)
                ->orWhere("stat_7", $stat)
                ->orWhere("stat_8", $stat)
                ->orWhere("stat_9", $stat)
                ->orWhere("stat_10", $stat)
                ->orWhere("stat_11", $stat);
        }
    }

    $item->groupBy("type_id");
    $items = $item->paginate(15);
    $items->appends($appends);

    return view("equipment.index", [
        "items" => $items,
        "types" => Types::all(),
        "stats" => EquipmentStats::all(),
        "classes" => CLasses::all(),
        "qualities" => EquipmentQualities::all()
    ]);
}
```

How can this be achieved in my controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `groupBy` to group equipments by `type_id`

```
$items = $item->paginate(15);

$itemsCollection = $items->groupBy(function($item) {
    return $item->type_id;
});

$items = new \Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator($itemsCollection, $items->total(), $items->perPage());
$items->appends($appends);
```

Then in your view

```
@foreach($types as $type)
    <h1>{{ $type->name }}</h1>
    <div class="list">
        <ul>
            @if ($items->has($type->id))
                @foreach($items->get($type->id))
                    <li>
                        {{ $item->name }}
                    </li>
                @endforeach
            @else
                <li>No results found.</li>
            @endif
        </ul>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: I get `Method Illuminate\Support\Collection::appends does not exist.` (if below paginate)

Comment: Thats because `$items` is no longer a paginator. You need to create a new paginator. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are looking for is `types` with `equipments`. So use eager loading.

**Controller**

```php
public function index()
{
    $types = Type::with(['equipments' => $this->searchScope()])->get();

    return view("equipment.index", [
        "types" => $types,
        ... // other things
    ]);
}

protected function searchScope()
{
    return function($query) {

        $request = request();

        $appends = [];

        foreach(["type_id", "sockets", "quality_id", "one_hand"] as $field) {
            if($request->has($field)) {
                $appends[$field] = $request->input($field);
                $query->where($field, $request->input($field));
            }
        }

        if($request->has("class")) {
            $appends["class"] = $request->input("class");
            $query->where(["class_id" => $request->input("class")])
                ->orWhere(["class_id2" => $request->input("class")], ["class_id3" => $request->input("class")]);
        }

        if($request->has("name")) {
            $appends["name"] = $request->input("name");
            $query->where("name", "like", "%" . $request->input("name") . "%");
        }

        if($request->has("stats")) {
            $stats = $request->input("stats");
            $appends["stats"] = $stats;
            foreach($stats as $stat) {
                $query->where("stat_1", $stat)
                    ->orWhere("stat_2", $stat)
                    ->orWhere("stat_3", $stat)
                    ->orWhere("stat_4", $stat)
                    ->orWhere("stat_5", $stat)
                    ->orWhere("stat_6", $stat)
                    ->orWhere("stat_7", $stat)
                    ->orWhere("stat_8", $stat)
                    ->orWhere("stat_9", $stat)
                    ->orWhere("stat_10", $stat)
                    ->orWhere("stat_11", $stat);
            }
        }

        $query->groupBy("type_id");
    };
}
```

**View**

```php
@foreach($types as $type)
<h1>{{ $type->name }}</h1>
<div class="list">
    <ul>
        @forelse($type->equipments as $equipment)
        <li>
            {{ $equipment->name }}
        </li>
        @empty
        <li>No results found.</li>
        @endforelse
    </ul>
</div>
@endforeach
```

**NOTE**

To do so, you need to have defined `equipments` relationship on the `Type` model.

In case you haven't. Here is how.

**Type Model**

```php
class Type extends Model
{
    public function equipments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Equipment:class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this not take my search parameters, etc, in mind?

Comment: I'm getting `Unknown column 'equipment.equipment_types_id' in 'where clause' `